# Keyboard debounce problem after login

Tags: keyboard

My password has a double character in it. I can type in my password with no problems. After login, however, I have to wait about half a second when typing double characters.

As in: If I type classes, I get clases, unless I pause before typing the second 's'.

This problem extends to all keys (cursor, enter, backspace etc).
Ubuntu 12.10 daskeyboard all up to date. dual-boot with windows 7. Tried with usb->ps/2 adapter and direct usb connection. Keyboard repeat delay and repeat speed work perfectly.

Cheers for any help.

Chris.

Answer (score 6):

On Ubuntu Precise, go to:

`System Settings > Universal Access > Typing > Bounce Keys`

Set the toggle for Bounce Keys to `on` and adjust the delay to as short as is necessary to remove the bouncing issue, but not so short that you end up typing "adres" instead of "address".

I have a rather bouncy Dell keyboard (kept randomly sending the same key twice in a row) and this setting appears to have fixed it.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I should have read your answer more carefully at the time. Cheers, C:\>

Comment: If this answered your question you could mark it as accepted by clicking the check-mark on the left. Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

From System Settings, go into "Keyboard" settings and you should see a window that looks like this:

[image: All Settings -> Keyboard]

Check the value of the "Delay" slider, make some adjustments (probably down) and test it out.

Comment: I tried that. The login screen is fine. It's a session problem. adjusting 'delay' to 0 makes no difference. Otherwise rock-solid.

Comment: debouncing (ignoring a quick double-hit) is different than a key repeat delay.